# HTML: playing random song from a playlist by clicking a custom button?

Tags: html, audio

I am trying to get the following:

- Simple HTML website.
- Custom button on it
- When clicked, it should play a random audio file from a playlist
- When clicked again, another random audio file from the playlist should start playing. and so on.

I already did it with one audio file by using this:

But i have no idea what to do to get it working with a playlist and and playing a random song from it.

Comment: provide the code that you mentioned

Comment: Removed the irrelevant thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use some Javascript to create a [random number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp), which needs to be between zero (or one depending on how you've got the audio arranged, as far as indexes). Link the JS to the button click.